# Could I use an old Javascript file with a new CSS file in Materialize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

This is my short problem, in my page I have an old version of Materialize, and I have seen in the last version of it that they have added the class "xl" to define grid's sizes.
If I upgrade all files, my page will break, because for example, in my JS file I open the modals with the function "leanModal()" and in the new version they use "modal()" and if I upgrade it, is a lot of time!!.

My questions is the next:

If I only need the class "xl" can I upgrade only the CSS File? If I would make it, would have a problem in the future with the JS File?

**My version of Materialize:** v0.97.7 (2014-2015)

**The actual version of Materialize:** v0.98.1 (2017-Now)

Comment: ctrl+f ... replace... or in any good ide/text editor there's a find a replace function. Just use that instead of hacking around.

Comment: @WilomGfx Thank you Wilom! You have reason with the replace function, I'll try to use it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You will have problems because the JavaScript calls specific classes in the CSS for that version.

Comment: Yes I suppose It's gonna happen it, so I'll try another method, Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not all that familiar with Materialize but I believe it has components that are implemented with a mix of CSS, HTML and JS. If you are using any of these components then yes, there's a possibility that other things might break. Typically these components will be expecting a certain HTML structure and CSS classes to be available/used. If the name of something has changed in one area of the framework then it's reasonable that something else could have changed elsewhere. You'd have to verify that yourself.

Comment: Yes, I would have just liked to see if there is some magic method to solve that problem, but I see now that is impossible, so let's do it! Haha Thank you!